# How to add a Template/DataTemplate to a TableCell

Tags: c#, xaml, templates, datatemplate, xmltable

I googled around but I did't find any really useful stuff;
my purpose is to display a specified `DataTemplate` for a specified `Class`:

```
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Table BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CellSpacing="0">
                <Table.Columns>
                    <TableColumn></TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn></TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn></TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn></TableColumn>
                </Table.Columns>
                <Table.RowGroups>
                    <TableRowGroup >
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>DataTemplate1</TableCell>//class1
                            <TableCell>DataTemplate2</TableCell>//class2
                            <TableCell>DataTemplate3</TableCell>//class3
                            <TableCell>DataTemplate4</TableCell>//class4
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup> 
                </Table.RowGroups>
            </Table>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Important it must be a XAML only solution because I load this xaml per `XamlReader.Load()` so there wont be a codebehind file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each type that you need a template for you can define a DataTemplate with just a DataType attribute somewhere in Resources. To get them to show up you'll need to then bind the data items to some ContentControl in your cells. Here's an example with templates for int and bool and bindings to collection items:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
  <FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Int32}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='A number: {0}'}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Boolean}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='A bool: {0}'}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Resources>
  <FlowDocument>
    <Table BorderBrush="Black"
           BorderThickness="1"
           CellSpacing="0">
      <Table.Columns>
        <TableColumn></TableColumn>
        <TableColumn></TableColumn>
        <TableColumn></TableColumn>
        <TableColumn></TableColumn>
      </Table.Columns>
      <Table.RowGroups>
        <TableRowGroup>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <BlockUIContainer>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding MixedTypeList[0]}" />
              </BlockUIContainer>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <BlockUIContainer>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding MixedTypeList[1]}" />
              </BlockUIContainer>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <BlockUIContainer>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding MixedTypeList[2]}" />
              </BlockUIContainer>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableRowGroup>
      </Table.RowGroups>
    </Table>
  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Comment: is there really no easier way to do this ?

Comment: What do you find difficult about this?

Comment: teher is nothing difficult on your answer just many copy paste that i that i hopped to deni because normally i bind like `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel}"><vw:View/></DataTemplate>` in my `ResourceDictionary` so i was thinking i could do similar things